# No viable overloaded '=' at std::vector

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I have this c++ program with the following types:

```
typedef pcl::PointXYZI PointType;
typedef pcl::PointCloud<PointType> PointCloudType;
typedef std::vector<PointCloudType::Ptr> CloudPtrList;
```

and this in main:

```
CloudPtrList clusterPtr(2);
   
    for (int i = 0; i < clusterPtr.size(); ++i)
    {
        clusterPtr[i] = boost::make_shared<PointCloudType>();
    }
```

And i keep getting this error ' no viable overloaded =' when i try to initialize this vector (the for above)

```
clusterPtr[i] = boost::make_shared<PointCloudType>();
```

This is the full error:

```
 No viable overloaded '='

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:3737:17: Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'typename boost::detail::sp_if_not_array<PointCloud<PointXYZI> >::type' (aka 'shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> >') to 'const std::__1::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> >' for 1st argument
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:3748:17: Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'typename boost::detail::sp_if_not_array<PointCloud<PointXYZI> >::type' (aka 'shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> >') to 'std::__1::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> >' for 1st argument
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:3745:9: Candidate template ignored: could not match 'std::__1::shared_ptr' against 'boost::shared_ptr'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:3756:9: Candidate template ignored: could not match 'std::__1::shared_ptr' against 'boost::shared_ptr'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:3766:9: Candidate template ignored: could not match 'auto_ptr' against 'shared_ptr'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:3790:9: Candidate template ignored: could not match 'unique_ptr' against 'shared_ptr'
```

Comment: what is PointCloudType::Ptr?

Comment: @user253751 [From the documentation](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/singletonpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html#a86473dec40d705190c6b2c2f795b9f15), in this case it is a `boost::shared_ptr<PointCloudType>`.

Comment: could add the complete error message?

Comment: ... and a [mre] so that we can reproduce the same error.

Comment: this is the complete error message.. and I put PointCloudType::Ptr above where are all the types (first code snippet). It should be just a std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI>> clusterPtr(2) and in for the initialization for this vector

Comment: There's no way "no viable overloaded =" is the full error message. It should tell you what types are involved.

Comment: Then might be this: 1. Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'typename boost::detail::sp_if_not_array<PointCloud<PointXYZI> >::type' (aka 'shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> >') to 'const std::__1::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> >' for 1st argument

Comment: @user10293932 Please add any new information to your question with an [edit].

Comment: Is `clusterPtr` actually const? That seems to be what the error message is saying.

Comment: no, it's not. the second code snippet is all i wrote and i get this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen in the error message ...

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:3737:17: Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'typename boost::detail::sp_if_not_array<PointCloud<PointXYZI> >::type' (aka 'shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> >') to 'const std::__1::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> >' for 1st argument
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/memory:3748:17: Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'typename boost::detail::sp_if_not_array<PointCloud<PointXYZI> >::type' (aka 'shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> >') to 'std::__1::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> >' for 1st argument
```

...you are using a newer version of `PCL` in which `boost::shared_ptr` has been replaced by `std::shared_ptr`:

```
#include <pcl/common/projection_matrix.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>

//#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>   // boost::make_shared
#include <memory>                    // std::make_shared

typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZI> PointCloudType;

int main() {
    std::vector<PointCloudType::Ptr> clusterPtr(2);

    for(int i = 0; i < clusterPtr.size(); ++i) {
        clusterPtr[i] = std::make_shared<PointCloudType>();   // std::make_shared
    }
}
```